# Angular 7 two-way binding: pipe taking an array as argument does not work as expected

Tags: arrays, angular, pipe, angular7, two-way-binding

I have written an Angular 7 pipe that takes 2 arguments: an array to filter and an array of matching filters.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { Order } from '../models';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterOrdersByDate'
})
export class CapacityOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(orders: Order[], periods: string[]): Order[] {

    if (!orders) return [];
    if (!periods.length) return orders;

    return orders.filter(function(order: Order) {

      for (var i=0; i<periods.length; i++) if (order.crossId.indexOf(periods[i])>-1) return true;
      return false;

    });

  }

}
```

orders is an array of orders, as defined in the Order model. Each order has a crossId property. This is an array of strings representing a starting date.

In my component.ts I have this method to add/remove a date from the periods array:

```
toggleOrder(date: string) {
  let i = this.filters.orders.indexOf(date);
  (i<0)? this.filters.orders.push(date) : this.filters.orders.splice(i, 1);
}
```

and this is the involved component.html code:

```
<mat-list class="list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let o of (data.orders | filterOrdersByDate : filters.orders)">
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <h3 mat-line>Order: {{o.group}}-{{o.number}}</h3>
    ...
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

...

<div *ngFor="let f of filters">
<mat-checkbox color="primary" [indeterminate]="false" (change)="toggleOrder(f.date)">{{f.date}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

When I toggle a checkbox in the component.html, the toggleOrder() method adds or remove a date in the filters array. So, I expect the pipe will filter the data.orders array. Unfortunately, this does NOT work. I spent 2 hours searching for a solution and I found that, if I pass the filters array length to the pipe, everything works as expected. So, it seems Angular set the two-way binding to the filters array length but not to the filters array itself.

How does this works? I expect Angular sets a two-way binding to every properties defined in the component class: strings, arrays, numbers, etc. But the pipe does not listen to changes in the array contents. Only if I pass the array length to the pipe, it works. But if I have a pipe that takes a string to filter data instead of an array, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) it talks about scenarios such as these. It [discourages](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-pipes) pipes operating on arrays in this way due to their poor performance.

What you are trying to achieve, as is, in one of two ways.

You could update your pipe to be an 'impure' pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterOrdersByDate',
  pure: false
})
```

Or you could keep it as a pure pipe and allow Angular to pick up on your changes by utilizing the built in change detection by reassigning the array value every time.

```
toggleOrder(date: string) {
  let i = this.filters.orders.indexOf(date);
  (i<0)? this.filters.orders.push(date) : this.filters.orders.splice(i, 1);
  this.filters.orders = this.filters.orders.slice(0);
}
```

As stated initially though, this is not the most optimal way to perform this task. I would stick with Angular's recommendations and move this pipe to a method that can be called from your `toggleOrder` method instead.

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes
>   property and take control over when and how often to execute the
>   supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe
>   and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting
>   service and injected into the component.